# How to find the pixel size of the camera of an iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I am writing an application which needs to know the angular dimensions of the pixels of an iOS camera imaging a scene with image plane at virtual infinity. In order to do this I need to know the focal length of the camera and the size of a camera pixel.  I would also like this application to run on multiple iOS devices and support future iOS devices that haven't been released yet.  So I would like to be able to be able to get the information that I need from the iOS device itself.

I have been able to find the real physical focal length of the lens in the EXIF metadata for the images, but I have not been able to locate any field in the EXIF or the "makerapple" meta data that tells me what the pixel size is.

At first I attempted to use the effective 35mm focal length that is found in the image meta data and an image size equivalent to a 35mm photo and divide by the linear number of pixels in the width of the image to determine an 35mm effective pixel size.  But the image aspect ratio of iOS devices never matches up exactly with the aspect ratio of 35mm film and the effective pixel size that I calculate from these values turns out to be off by approximately 3%.  I verified this by taking an image of a scene with known dimensions and comparing the actual angular distances with those calculated using the above technique. This is too large an error for my application to work correctly.

From a teardown report on one particular iPhone device that I use for testing I was able to get the actual pixel size of the CMOS sensor. Using the focal length of the camera obtained from the EXIF I was able to calculate the an angular pixel size that agreed with the actual dimensions of my measurement image to a little better than 1%.  This is sufficient accuracy for allowing my application to work acceptably.  However, if this data is not stored somewhere on the device itself and accessible to the app, the only other alternative I see is generating my own database with the dimensions of each device and having to update that database each time a new device is released.  This seems like a fairly painful solution that may be beyond my resources to support.

Can anyone help with this and let me know if the information I need is stored somewhere on the device?

Comment: Hi T.Barret
Did you manage to find out anything about it?
I see that no one has answered your question.